# Iphone application gets stuck after unlocking screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i keep my application open for awhile, the iPhone/iPod locks the screen. When i unlock it my application gets stuck for like 2 seconds and then it resumes and keep functioning as usual. Why is this ? and how can i prevent it ?

To prevent this from hapenning is there any `PLIST` method where we could stop the process of the application when it goes to a locked screen (Might not be a better idea)

Comment: did you find anything for this? this is happening with me too...

Comment: I don't think I remember the solution, since I posted this 5 years ago. But, I think it was due to a memory issue. The method `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` should help you to verify if its memory issue. Also as @Alex states you can goto ` Product > Profile > Leaks ` to track memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the answer for your first question (you maybe do some heavy things inside the applicationDidBecomeActive method or the app simply reallocates memory), but i can answer the second one.

You can simply prevent the auto lock by calling:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];`
A good palce for this is inside the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of the app delegate.

Comment: Where should i add this ? and does apple encourage to kill the app once its in an idle state ?

Comment: The best place for this is inside the applicationDidFinishLaunching method of the app delegate. Updated the answer with that.
And yes, iOS kills certain apps when it needs the resources.

Answer (score 0):

In your application delegate do you have any code that could slow down your app? Check the following methods?

- -(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- -(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
- -(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
- -(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
- -(void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

Also use the above methods ensure you application suspends properly.

Log when your app receives a memory warning inside:

```
-(void) applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
```

Maybe when you suspend or reopen your app some there is a memory issue.

Comment: I don't have anything in those methods. How could i suspend the app properly ? How could i print a memory warning in the `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` method ?

Comment: In applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning just say NSLog(@"received a memory warning"). Run your app using Product > Profile > Leaks to track the memory leaks.